# Method for triggering certain click event using .trigger() but suppressing all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My situation is that I am trying to trigger a single event using the jQuery `.trigger()` method. However the element I am triggering has multiple click event listeners.

Actually finding what these listeners are and what they trigger from the source code is probably not viable as its included in the sites main JS file and its all minified and pretty much unreadable.

At the moment I know that the element when clicked performs some kind of ajax call and loads more data into the DOM of the page (which is what i want to trigger), however it also displays an overlay (which is what I want to suppress temporarily).

As its just an overlay there are workaround I can make; using a `display:none` on it straight after click etc. However it would be much more elegant if i could somehow suppress all click events on this element except the desired event.

Any ideas if this is actually possible? And if so how I would go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your own event at the top of the event chain. And cancel the event chain in your event. Here is a solution with writing a custom jquery extention.

```
$.fn.bindFirst = function (which, handler) {
  var $elm = $(this);
  $elm.unbind(which, handler);
  $elm.bind(which, handler);
  var events = $._data($elm[0]).events;
  var registered = events[which];
  registered.unshift(registered.pop());
  events[which] = registered;
}

$("#elm").bindFirst("click", function(e) {
   // edit: seems like preventing event does not work
   // But your event triggers first anyway.
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Reference:
https://gist.github.com/infostreams/6540654

EDIT: 
https://jsfiddle.net/8nb9obc0/2/
I made a jsFiddle and it seems like event preventing does not work in this example. There might be another solution.

Comment: cheers noldor this seems like what I am looking for. To be honest the method is a little beyond my JS experience. Any chance you could break it down a little and include example arguments?

Comment: @Ash "$.fn.bindFirst" is a jquery extention method to bind an event to your element (equivalent of current "bind" or "on" methods in jquery). You can use it in a seperate javascript file and reference in your html. But seems like i was wrong about canceling the event chain. It didn't work properly in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/8nb9obc0/2/